# Function returning jQuery element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a JS function which returns the first button element from the given container, I have written following code,

```
let getLastWizardFooterBtn = function(wizardContainer) {
  let wizardFooter = $(wizardContainer).find('.wizard-footer');
  return $(wizardFooter).find('button:enabled:last');
};
```

But the issue is that even-though I have a DOM element present, this function returns undefined.

Here are the screenshots from Chrome developer tools.

[image]

But as I have debugger set on this line and when I run the same function in Console Tab, I get proper output.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The strange thing is that the variables which I declare are showing undefined but those auto generated variables starting with `_` is showing correct values.

[image]

Can someone please point out why it is behaving like this?

(Because as you can see that I am listening KeyDown event on that container so that DOM element is present for sure.)

Thanks in advance.

**======================**

**UPDATE: Issue got resolved once I change the variable names as suggested by Christoph Herold in comment sections**

Comment: Can you add the markup as well?

Comment: Is the DOM loaded before executing the function?

Comment: @EsliS Yes, I am listening in keydown event on that container.

Comment: I assume that particular element is not present in the DOM when the JS is run

Comment: This does not make any sense. Even if the DOM element wasn't there, you should at least get a jQuery object with 0 entries. `undefined` can only be returned, if the definition of your function is maybe not in your scope. Could you check in the debugger, in the line of your call, what `getLastWizardFooterBtn` actually is? I assume, it is not the function you expect.

Comment: @ChristophHerold I have attached more screenshots from debugger window, What you said is correct even I was expecting query object but somehow it is returning undefined.

Comment: That makes even less sense. The debugger gives you the correct result, but the variable is not being assigned?! Is there maybe some funny whitespace in your code, or could you try renaming your variable to something other than `btn`? I don't know, if it will really help, but it's the only idea I currently have.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] that clearly show your issue.

Comment: I see that you have some sort of source mapping in place. That suggests your code is minified in some form. Could it be, that minification broke something. Could you please try it with the unminified code, to see if it works?

Comment: @ChristophHerold Please check the screenshot of Scope window.

Comment: I just posted an answer so you have something to mark :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, something breaks during your minification process, or some code just wasn't properly updated. Try renaming your variable or using the unminified code to see, if that at least works. The basic code looks correct.